# Access outer structure from inner one

Tags: go

I have a question similar to this one: [accessing struct fields from embedded struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537549/accessing-struct-fields-from-embedded-struct), except that instead of the embedded structure a just have a nested one.

Basically, what I need is the possibility to access the outer structure from the nested one. However, the composing approach suggested in the accepted answer, doesn't fit my current "structure of structures", thus it's not really applicable without some cumbersome refactoring.

Instead, I have come up with an idea of embedding pointer to the outer structure into the inner one:

```golang
type Outer struct {
    someField   int
    innerStruct Inner
}

type Inner struct {
    outerStruct *Outer
}

func test() {
    outer := Outer{someField:123}
    inner := Inner{outerStruct:&outer}
    outer.innerStruct = inner
    println(inner.outerStruct.someField) // just to test
}
```

So, now I wonder, whether ideologically it's a valid approach for Go? And are there any possible drawbacks to this method?

Comment: It's technically valid, whether it's good is a matter of subjective opinion. The possible drawbacks are probably obvious - ending up with a pointer to the wrong outer object, or no pointer to the outer object, or retaining the inner object with its pointer after the outer isn't needed preventing the outer from being GC'd, that sort of thing. I would generally think that if you need this, your design probably needs work; the inner is *tightly coupled* to the outer, which is a bad sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a pointer to the outer struct is the only way to do it. The drawback is that you have to make sure that the pointer is initialized. So, something like a constructor function might help:

```
func NewOuter() *Outer {
  ret:=Outer{}
  ret.outer=&ret
  return &ret
}
```

Also, you have to mind how you pass `Outer` around, because the pointer in the inner struct might end up pointing to an instance of Outer you don't expect:

```
func f(o Outer) {
   g(&o)
}
```

Above, `g` will get an instance of `Outer` with a pointer pointing to an instance of `Outer` different from the one it got.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you need to make sure that you never make a copy of Outer as the copy's Inner will point to the wrong Outer.

See sync.Mutex or WaitGroup for how to make a struct that cannot be copied.